# Typescript in Visual Studio 2022 - on-the-fly compilation

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, asp.net-core

In Asp.net MVC (.net Framework) projects if I made a change into a typescript file - I can immediately see changes in corresponding js-file.

Now I'm trying Asp.net core 6.0 in Visual Studio 2022. And typescripts are compiled only when all the project is compiled (built).
How can I make it compile typescripts on-the-fly there?
(which means I save changes to TS, immediately open corresponding JS and see those changes reflected there)

Comment: not sure, but there's an `watch` option in the `tsconfig.json`, you might want to take a look into that

Comment: Emm correction: there was no on-the-fly TS compilation in asp.net core 3.1. it was so in asp.net MVC :\

I'll edit my question

Comment: @PatrickBeynio thanks for the idea, but it makes project build process to hang :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable the option "compileOnSave" and it should work, as it works for me (Asp.net core 6.0 in Visual Studio 2022):

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions" : {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: wow thanks! :)
I wonder how does it work. there should be TS compiler running in background

Comment: well, if you have Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild nuget package installed, it does the job. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/

Answer (score 0):

After some research I think that Asp.net core projects don't support the on-fly typescript compilation like it was in asp.net MVC (Framework).
To achieve it we should use Task Runner Explorer to run typescript permanent compilation ("tsc -watch") on project load.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommandTaskRunner - this plugin could help, but it doesn't support Visual Studio 2022 yet. SO I'll continue researching, maybe will try to achieve it via https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner or Gulp/Grunt